# What does DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)BindKeyT, BindKeyD); mean? Attaching a detour to a memory address

Tags: c++, c, detours

This is just a simple question. I've been reading the source of something which attaches to a memory address of a subroutine using `DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)BindKeyT, BindKeyD);` where `BindKeyT` is the address to a subroutine in memory. I'm curious, what exactly does `(&(PVOID &)` mean in english? I understand that `PVOID` is a void pointer, but how does this get translated into a function which can be used to attach a detour to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terry Mahaffey is right, what you are passing is a pointer to a pointer to the function. This is commonly used whenever the function you are passing the pointer to (in this case, DetourAttach) wants to return more than one value, and one of those returned values is a pointer. Since functions in C/C++ can only return a single value, the only way to obtain multiple values from them is via pointers.

A simple example would be when one wishes to return a pointer to a block of allocated memory. Then one can write a function like:

```
int allocstr(int len, char **retptr)
 {
  char *p = malloc(len + 1); /* +1 for \0 */
  if(p == NULL)
   return 0;
  *retptr = p;
  return 1;
 }
```

To answer your other question, of how to setup a memory address to be used as a function, one can do it like so:

```
void* (void * BindKeyT)(const char* key) = actual_BindKeyT;

// actual_BindKeyT is a pointer to a function that will be defined elsewhere, 
// and whose declaration you will include in your project through a header file
// or a dll import

void * BindKeyD(const char* key)
{
    // Code for your hook function
}

DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)BindKeyT, BindKeyD);
```

(taken from http://zenersblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/api-hooking-with-detours-part-1.html)

Bear in mind that the declarations for BindKeyT and BindKeyD should match.

Comment: So let's say that I had this address "x", would I pass x* in place of actual_BindKeyT if I wanted to use BindKeyT as a function?

Comment: You would pass &x.
x* points to the function, and &x is the address of x. DetourAttach wants a reference to the reference

Answer (score 1):

The C++ parser in my head (which is not bug free) says that it is a C style cast of BindKeyT to a reference to a pointer to void  - the (PVOID&) part - and then taking the address of that - the & in front. So the result of the expression is a pointer to a pointer to the function.

Comment: Now assuming that it's a pointer to a pointer to the function, how can I setup the memory address to simply be a function and be called so?

Comment: AFAIK DetourAttach requires a pointer to a pointer to a function, so you need to use that syntax (or introduce a temporary pointer, and take the address of that).

Answer (score 0):

There is an introduction to Detours here: [api-hooking-with-detours-part-1](http://zenersblog.blogspot.com/2008/04/api-hooking-with-detours-part-1.html)